# SendKey without needed to set focus

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

I am searching for a way to send keys to a control (which is on my form which is executing SendKeys.Send() now) without setting the Window as Focused Window. The Mainproblem with SendKeys.Send() is, that in debugging the key goes to VisualStudio.
The control, which I have to send keys is on my Form. I ask me, if there is a way to direct "send" them a key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending keys to inactive application in C#/.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584767/sending-keys-to-inactive-application-in-c-net)

Comment: If the form is part of your application, you should be able to set the text directly. With more details, we can guide you toward that.

Comment: There is a related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172353/how-to-push-a-key-and-release-it-using-c // Please consider the newest answer